# Woocommerce won't send notification to Gmail

Tags: wordpress, email, gmail, woocommerce

I've been developing an e-commerce website and it comes to the last phase of development. However, I've found one error during my test.

When I use email that has @domainname.com, the email went through but when I tried using gmail - both admin and customer emails - the notification email didn't reach gmail inbox at all.

Do you have any idea what is wrong or there should be some additional plugin that I have to install.

Any answer is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Would the email send to a yahoo or hotmail account?

Comment: I've had this same issue before. It was solved by using two fixes: 1) Set an SPF record on the domain you're sending from so that Gmail trusts the email. 2) It also ended up that the small size of my VPS was causing memory errors and some emails wouldn't send at all. I had to get a bigger VPS.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce (and many times WordPress in general) can be difficult to get working with reliable email delivery.  Most of the time it's because your site is on a shared host (shared IP address) and if you're hosted with other sites that are a bit *spammy* it can hurt you.  (WordPress will use your host's SMTP server by default and your actual email service might not be hosted with them, so your MX records probably don't match the same provider / IP block).

When you add the fact that your WooCommerce emails have content that has anything to do with money (using the words "order" "shipping" "prices" etc) it raises your chances of getting caught up in a spam filter.  (And yes, Gmail will many times not even deliver your email... And it won't even go into the spam folder).

I've had great success with using a third party SMTP provider.  The main benefits are

- You emails are relayed through their trusted network
- They verify ownership of your domain (and sending domain) so that Gmail also trusts it
- They many times provide reliability reports and delivery success / failure reports

I personally use [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) (by MailChimp).  It's completely free to send up to 12K emails per month (which is usually more than enough for most small businesses).  Get their WordPress plugin [wpMandrill](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/) so that you can see your delivery stats right in your dashboard and so that WordPress uses the relay automatically (including WooCommerce).  Your client will probably appreciate seeing that too anyway.

I've played with Mailgun and Sendgrid a bit, but I really like Mandrill.  Check the others out to see if they'll be a better fit for you too.